# Can the useState() hook's passed function re-render their component multiple times inside a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've tried searching for this problem but the searches have come up completely empty. I'm relatively new to the JS frameworks. The project I'm working on now is a sorting algorithm visualizer with ReactJS which is supposed to demonstrate how different sorts work step by step. However, I'm having a problem with re-rendering the displayed array every time I call the my setArray() function (the one I used in my useState hook) inside the sorting function.

There's also a recorded video of the problem in the end.
I'm using the <div>'s heights to do the sorting. Here is the bubble sort implementation:

```
    
    // The hook's definition
    const [ array, setArray ] = useState(generateArray(rangeVal));

    //---
    // Code inbetween
    //---

    const bubble_Sort = () => {
        let list = document.getElementsByClassName('array-container')[0];
        let realList = list.children;

        let swapp;
        let n = realList.length-1;
        let x = [...array];
        do {
            swapp = false;
            for (let i=0; i < n; i++)
            {
                let a = x[i].props.style.height;
                let b = x[i+1].props.style.height;

                if (a > b)
                {
                    console.log('inside');
                    let temp = x[i];
                    x[i] = x[i+1];
                    x[i+1] = temp;
                    swapp = true;

                    // This, I think, is the problematic part
                    newArray(x); // Shown below
                    sleep(10); // A custom sleep function I wrote that basically stalls the code
                }
            }
            n--;
        } while (swapp);
    }
```

And this is the newArray() method that's supposed to update the array shown on screen every time it's called

```
    const newArray = (newArray) => {
        setArray([...newArray]);
    }
```

I'd imagine that every time 2 values get swapped in the sort, the updated array would be shown on the screen through newArray() method since calling my hook's setArray() function should re-render the whole component.

However, what happens is that the whole component remains frozen until the entire array is sorted and only gets shown in its sorted form after the sorting has ended.

I have no idea why this is happening. I'm assuming this has something to do with multiple setArray() calls not working inside a single function, but even if it's so, I can't come up with a solution. Your help would greatly be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I recorded a video in case seeing the execution helps:
https://streamable.com/hbjk2z

**Edit:**
The sleep function: https://i.ibb.co/p2CypFK/image-2020-11-13-015800.png

Comment: Why are you adding the `sleep` call?  What does your implementation of `sleep` look like?

Comment: *I'd imagine that every time 2 values get swapped in the sort, the updated array would be shown on the screen* - this is an incorrect assumption. Calling a state updater function does not trigger an **immediate** re-render, it just signals that the component **will** need to re-render.

Comment: @jmargolisvt It's nothing fancy. Just something I thought might solve the problem but did't :/

https://i.ibb.co/p2CypFK/image-2020-11-13-015800.png

Comment: @BrianThompson I see. With the sort, there are guaranteed to be multiple calls to the state updater before the sorting finishes. If my deduction is correct, is it that the those calls won't be executed until the sorting finishes first?

Comment: It's internal react optimisation to minimize the number of costly DOM operations required to update the UI. You can try to write recursive function with timeout